# Why is go.Sankey() showing no output? (plotly.graph_output, python)

Tags: python, plotly, dashboard

I'm new to Plotly, so I'm hoping this will be an easy answer...
I'm creating a web app dashboard and I want to have one of my subplots be Sankey. The output is absolutely nothing, just white space. Here's the section of my code with the Sankey chart:

```
subfig.add_trace(
    go.Sankey(
        node=dict(
            pad=15,
            thickness=20,
            line=dict(color='black', width=0.5),
            label=testdf['Label'].tolist(),
            color='blue'
        ),
        link=dict(
            source=testdf['Source'].tolist(),
            target=testdf['Target'].tolist(),
            value=testdf['Value'].tolist()
        )
    ), row=3, col=1)
```

And here's the appearance on my web app, under "By Condition Type and Condition":
[image]

Can I not use go.Sankey() as a subplot? Am I not calling the function correctly? SOS!

Update: gflavia suggested I add the type in the subplot specs, but I've already done that (I could have done it incorrectly though):

```
    rows=5, cols=4,
    specs=[
        [{},                {'colspan':2},      None,                   {}],
        [{'colspan':4},     None,               None,                   None],
        [{'type':'sankey','rowspan':3, 'colspan':3}, None,      None,                   {}],
        [None,              None,      None,                   {}],
        [None,              None,      None,                   {}]
    ],
    subplot_titles=("By Age","By Percent of Ethnicity/Race Population", "By Sex", 'By State', 'By Condition Type and Condition', 'Compared to Other Viruses', 'By U.S. Region', 'By Place of Death' )
)
```

Comment: You probably need to add the subplot types in the `specs` property of `make_subplots`, see https://plotly.com/python/subplots/#subplots-types.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I made an update on the original post to show you what I've done with that.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)?